# Struggling to display images using django

Tags: python, html, django, dynamic

I am creating a blogging website using django framework and so I am struggling to display images on dynamic pages. Here is my code:

models.py:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name= 'blog_posts')
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    content = models.TextField()
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=Status, default=0)
    cover_image = models.ImageField()
    captioned_image = models.ImageField()
    caption = models.CharField(max_length=300)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created_on']
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

views.py:

```
def post(request, slug):
    post = Post.objects.get(slug = slug)
    context = {'post': post}
    return render(request, template_name='blogger/pages.html', context=context)
```

within my html:

```
<img class="img-fluid" src="{{post.cover_image.url}}" />
```

I am unsure what I am doing incorrect here as text is correctly displaying in my code dynamically, just unable to work with images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple things that might be going wrong. Are you using the development server that comes packaged with Django or a production server? Django doesn't serve media files during development by default. You need to enable it by putting this in your `url.py`

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    ...]
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,
                          document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Also, make sure you have MEDIA_ROOT AND MEDIA_URL configured. The most basic way of doing this is adding this to your settings.py

```
# Base url to serve media files
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

# Path where media is stored
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
```

If neither of these fix the issue, it might be helpful for us to see the output of your terminal where the server is running and/or what the network tab in your developer tools looks like (make sure to just select images so it's easier to read)

Comment: Yep, this fixed it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Provide an "upload_to" for your image field so that your images upload there.

```
cover_image = models.ImageField(upload_to="Folder")
```

Comment: still no, actually it is succesfully uploading the files to the folder when i upload via admin site, but it is unable to render in html

Comment: Trying installing pillow module. ```pip install pillow```

Comment: yes that is already installed

Comment: Try to see the src of cover_image by View page source in your browser.